# Android start service from link?

Tags: android, service

Is it possible to start Service from link. I try with code below but it is impossible to start.

Link:

```
"<a href=\"com.example.tohome://deeplink/home/inbox?id=3\">test to launch myapp</a> <br /><br />"
```

Example:

```
 <service android:name=".PrintService"
            android:enabled="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="com.example.tohome" android:host="deeplink"/>
            </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry. Browsers, to the extent they honor custom schemes, will only use them to start activities. You are welcome to have a `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` activity, though, that starts the service and then calls `finish()`, all from `onCreate()`.

Comment: Each and every answer from you is a free teaching class. Many thanks. You are the guy.